# New error when editing membership: Argument 1 passed to CRM_Financial_BAO_Order::setOverrideTotalAmount() must be of the type float, string given

Tags: civimember

This error seems to be connected with the update to version 5.36 as it just appeared after that.

When editing an existing membership or adding a new membership the following error appears in the logs:

`TypeError: Argument 1 passed to CRM_Financial_BAO_Order::setOverrideTotalAmount() must be of the type float, string given, called in C:\wamp64\www\civicrmd8\httpdocs\sites\all\modules\civicrm\CRM\Member\Form.php on line 486 in CRM_Financial_BAO_Order->setOverrideTotalAmount() (line 152 of C:\wamp64\www\civicrmd8\httpdocs\sites\all\modules\civicrm\CRM\Financial\BAO\Order.php).`

I feel it could be connected to https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/19476/files

A quick fix I found was to change line 486 of civicrm/CRM/Member/Form.php from

`$this->order->setOverrideTotalAmount($formValues['total_amount']);`

to

`$this->order->setOverrideTotalAmount((int) $formValues['total_amount']);`

But I am not quite sure if this really solves the issue or what sideeffects I do not see. Maybe this type casting should be done earlier in the process? or maybe the problem lies somewhere else? In my case the value of $formValues['total_amount'] is an empty string but I do not know where this value comes from.

Comment: thanks Tobias. It also impacted Stripe payment gateway

Comment: I'm seeing this issue too, in civiCRM version 5.36.0

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record - the issue is solved in CiviCRM version 5.36.1